# Is it possible to monitor role and privilege grant/revoke using triggers?

Tags: oracle, trigger, audit

Is it possible to monitor role and privilege grant/revoke using triggers? I' aware of doing that using Oracle audit tools however, it's interesting is it possible to do that using triggers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do that with DDL triggers (`[before|after] grant` or `revoke`).

The docs are in the [Oracle® Database PL/SQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e17126/triggers.htm). You should look carefully at the [event attribute functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e17126/triggers.htm#LNPLS794) table, and the [Event Attribute Functions for Client Event Triggers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e17126/triggers.htm#LNPLS797) section to know what information is available in those contexts.

Here's an example trigger (probably incomplete, this is just an example) that would log basic information about `grant` and `revoke` events, assuming a `log` table with appropriate columns:

```
create or replace trigger trigger1 after grant or revoke on database
  declare
    priv  dbms_standard.ora_name_list_t;
    who   dbms_standard.ora_name_list_t;
    npriv pls_integer;
    nwho  pls_integer;
  begin
    npriv := ora_privilege_list(priv);
    if (ora_sysevent = 'GRANT') then
      nwho := ora_grantee(who);
    else
      nwho := ora_revokee(who);
    end if;
    for i in 1..npriv
    loop
      for j in 1..nwho
      loop
        insert into log values
          (
            systimestamp,
            ora_sysevent,
            who(j),
            priv(i),
            ora_dict_obj_owner,
            ora_dict_obj_name
          );
      end loop;
    end loop;
  end;
```

Example:

```
SQL> grant select on log to bar;
Grant succeeded.

SQL> revoke select on log from bar;
Revoke succeeded.

SQL> select * from log;
DT                           WHAT   WHO PRIV   OWN OBJ
25-NOV-12 05.29.19.095403 PM GRANT  BAR SELECT MAT LOG
25-NOV-12 05.29.27.004610 PM REVOKE BAR SELECT MAT LOG
```

Answer (score 0):

Improvement: Added login user, IP Address. It will show who has given grant or revoke.

Log Table

```
create table log ( 
    Action_DaTe date
    , Pvs_name varchar2(15)
    , PRIVILEGE varchar2(30)
    , OWNER varchar(20)
    , OBJECT_NAME varchar2(30)
    , Username varchar2(30)
    , login_user varchar2(20)
    , IP_address varchar2(15)
);
```

Modified Trigger

```
create or replace trigger gr_trigger after grant or revoke on database
  declare
    priv  dbms_standard.ora_name_list_t;
    who   dbms_standard.ora_name_list_t;
    npriv pls_integer;
    nwho  pls_integer;
  begin
    npriv := ora_privilege_list(priv);
    if (ora_sysevent = 'GRANT') then
      nwho := ora_grantee(who);
    else
      nwho := ora_revokee(who);
    end if;
    for i in 1..npriv
    loop
      for j in 1..nwho
      loop
        insert into log values
          (
            systimestamp,
            ora_sysevent,
            priv(i),
            ora_dict_obj_owner,
            ora_dict_obj_name,
            who(j),
            ora_login_user,
            (NVL(ora_client_ip_address, 'N/A'))
          );
      end loop;
    end loop;
  end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that npriv is NULL for new Oracle 12c action names GRANT INHERIT PRIVILEGES and REVOKE INHERIT PRIVILEGES, hence your code must include a check for npriv is NOT NULL prior to FOR LOOP to avoid error on ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error.

Example:

**if npriv is not null then** 
for i in 1..npriv
    loop
...
...
**end if;**